# Duplicate Safari tabs on iOS and iPadOS

Tags: ios, safari, ipados, tabs

On macOS, it's really easy to duplicate tabs in Safari (control+click and choose Duplicate Tab), but there doesn't seem to be that option on iOS and iPadOS.

Interestingly, control-clicking on a tab in Safari on iPad does not propose the option to duplicate the tab :

[image]

On Apple Support, they provide a whole support page for the macOS case but none for iPadOS or iOS.

I have seen some answers (not here) that provide a Shortcuts solution but they don't work for me.

**Is it possible to duplicate tabs on iOS and/or iPadOS, if so, how?**

Note : I do not want to install any third-party app or use the copying/pasting method.

Comment: How about long pressing the tab in question, selecting “copy” then pasting it into a new tab?

Comment: @Allan I forgot to mention that I did not wanted this method.

Comment: What is the reason for not wanting this method.

Comment: @mmmmmm because I find it too long.

Comment: So, for a feature that doesn't exist as it does on macOS, you don't want either a third party app or a process that requires just one more step than the feature in macOS?  What exactly are your expectations here?

Comment: @Allan I am not looking for a one-step answer here. I just do not find practical doing the copy/paste process since it takes quite a lot of time for me who is using 2 Safari windows in Slide Over most of the time (the address bar is really small if there's more than 2 tabs in a window and it makes it hard to click on the tab to copy the link; also, having to go in tab view and long-clicking and selecting copy, opening new tab and pasting is quite annoying to me to do). I was hoping to find an answer that did not require having to perform such task. My iPad is managed centrally and I cannot ...

Comment: Continuation : I cannot install extensions to Safari. But I can on my iPhone but I needed a solution that could work for both iPhone and iPad so I mentioned that.

Comment: By discounting 3rd party solutions, and discounting the built-in you don't leave a lot of wiggle room for answers. There is no other solution, there is nothing 'hidden'. Unless you are duplicating tabs on an industrial scale, requiring some sort of batched solution (see my answer below), which of course is a ridiculous proposition, then an automated solution is overkill. Just use what's provided and stop making excuses.

Comment: Did you look for an extension that does this? Or, are you just posting questions for the sake of posting questions?

Comment: You probably can create a Shortcut to duplicate a tab, not sure it's simpler at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Really not that hard to work out. I despair of Shortcuts & AppleScript solutions that take longer to research, code & test, all for the sake of a single press; than using the facilities already built in. The only time they are appropriate is in a batch workflow. Yes, they require more button presses, but their atomic nature gives more flexibility for other purposes.

On iOS:

- Select the tabs view (2 overlapping squares)
- Long press on the page you want to duplicate, select Copy
- Add new tab (plus button)
- Long press address, Paste and Go

Comment: Something to note: unlike “duplicate tab” on macOS Safari, this does not retain the navigation history in the new tab.